# How can I solve this error? "Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting."

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I want to run my flutter project in simulator.However when I run I get this error."Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting.
Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting.
"
I tried almost all the stackoverflow solutions.Still have the same problem
I open Xcode.After chosing the simulator from Xcode I can run project,but from Visual Studio Code unable to run.

I made some adjustments (chose simator from Xcode) in Xcode but it did not help.